# Assign dictionary mapping labels to index values to a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, series

I want to use 'cluster1' dictionary to populate an empty `pandas series` called `Cluster`.

For some background about the data:

```
data.StringTogeth1
print(type(data.StringTogeth1))
print(type(data.StringTogeth1[0]))
```

Output:

```
    0                      love dog cute think
    1                           dog look weird
    2                  think look like cupacak
    3    want snowman thank jerk grrr make mad
    4        hey know time babi shark dodododo
    5                               dog awesom

    Name: StringTogeth1, dtype: object


<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'str'>
```

Input:

```
nclusters1 = 4
clusters1 = cluster_sentences(data.StringTogeth1, nclusters1)
data['Cluster'] = pd.Series()


print(clusters1)
```

Output:

```
{1: [0, 2], 2: [1, 5], 0: [3], 3: [4]}
```

So `clusters1` translates to

```
{cluster number: [index from series,index from series], etc..}
```

So the dataframe should look like this:

```
    Id  StringTogeth1                           Cluster
0   1   love dog cute think                     1
1   2   dog look weird                          2
2   3   think look like cupacak                 1
3   4   want snowman thank jerk grrr make mad   0
4   5   hey know time babi shark dodododo       3
5   6   dog awesom                              2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can flatten and invert `clusters1`, then assign it back:

```
df['Clusters'] = pd.Series({v: k for k, V in clusters1.items() for v in V})
df

   Id                          StringTogeth1  Clusters
0   0                    love dog cute think         1
1   1                         dog look weird         2
2   2                think look like cupacak         1
3   3  want snowman thank jerk grrr make mad         0
4   4      hey know time babi shark dodododo         3
5   5                             dog awesom         2
```

Where,

```
{v: k for k, V in clusters1.items() for v in V}
# {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 3, 5: 2}
```

...is a mapping of index to the cluster label.

Pro-tip: Initializing the column with an empty series is unnecessary.